# How to use Network Bound Resource with Paging 3?

Tags: android, api, pagination, android-room, android-paging

I want to use network-bound resources meaning room caching with paging 3. If someone has done it please post your answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NetworkBoundResource` from [architecture-components-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) is just a helper class wrapping access to a resource behind network + db cache. The canonical way to achieve this type of layered data in Paging is using `RemoteMediator`, which you can pass into `Pager`'s constructor.

`RemoteMediator` essentially acts as a callback which fires when `PagingSource` runs out of data to load from the DB, where you can then make a network fetch, write the new items into the DB and invalidate to get Paging to pick up the new items. This seems really roundabout, but it assures that you have a single source of truth, so all of items displayed and loaded in your app are based on what's in the DB.

Comment: No problem - there is a great guide here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db in case you need some more help with the implementation.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. Actually, I was searching with Network Bound Resources. But the thing which worked for me was actually with Remote Mediator. Thank again.